# Convert MYSQL query into Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.3

My query is :

```
SELECT * FROM drivers INNER JOIN vehicle ON drivers.vehicle_id = vehicle.id INNER JOIN cartype ON vehicle.cartype_id = cartype.id WHERE drivers.status = "free" AND vehicle.cartype_id = 1
```

Convert this query into laravel eloquent query .

I've tried harder but can't achieve !

Comment: Have you ready any of the documentation, at all?

Comment: I think this can be achieved easily using Laravel's relations. You may show your table relations to create a query using Laravel Eloquent ORM.

Comment: Is that so easy so convert me then ! I'm asking for it

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know what models and relationship between them you have - here is pure Query Builder request (pure translation of your sql, even if join with cartype table is redundant):

```
$result = DB::table("drivers")
    ->where("drivers.status", "free")
    ->join("vehicle", "drivers.vehicle_id", "=", "vehicle.id")
    ->join("cartype", "vehicle.cartype_id", "=", "cartype.id")
    ->where("vehicle.cartype_id", 1)->get()
```

Source: [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins), [API page](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/index.html).

Comment: Got it . Thanks !